# Jquery Repeater, how to make the 'create button' at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that the `data-repeater-create=""` must be inside the `id="left_repeater"`, otherwise it will not function as a create button. Is there a way that the button will function outside the `id="left_repeater"` or `id="right_repeater"`?

My goal is when I click `add left` button, it will only create the left input and vise versa for the `add right` button. Both of the button is at the very bottom.

[JS fiddle link to see the codes](https://jsfiddle.net/LearnProgramming/f9ck3L6j/6/)

```js
$('#left_repeater').repeater({
  show: function() {
    $(this).slideDown();
  },
});

$('#right_repeater').repeater({
  show: function() {
    $(this).slideDown();
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.repeater/1.2.1/jquery.repeater.min.js"></script>

<div id="left_repeater">
  <div data-repeater-list="left_items">
    <div data-repeater-item>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-sm m-input" placeholder="left">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div data-repeater-create="" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
         <span><i class="la la-plus"></i><span>Add</span></span>
     </div> -->
</div>

<div id="right_repeater">
  <div data-repeater-list="right_items">
    <div data-repeater-item>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-sm m-input" placeholder="right">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-repeater-create="" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
    <span><i class="la la-plus"></i><span>Add</span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 text-center">
    <div data-repeater-create="" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
      <span><i class="la la-plus"></i><span>Add Left</span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-6 text-center">
    <div data-repeater-create="" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
      <span><i class="la la-plus"></i><span>Add Right</span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the "buttom" the bottom of the butt? OMG I'm going to get banned but I couldn't resist, sorry :D -> []

Comment: Are you looking for this one? [https://jsfiddle.net/pb7Lnywh/](https://jsfiddle.net/pb7Lnywh/)

Answer (score 0):

Place the #left_repeater inside div container.

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="left_repeater">
     .....
   </div>
</div>
```

add CSS style to this

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/y1bpot5n//](https://jsfiddle.net/y1bpot5n/)

Comment: somewhat like this but the solution that you provided messed up the UI

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of the UI that you expect

Comment: It is exactly the UI that i provided in jsfiddle in the question

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/y1bpot5n/](https://jsfiddle.net/y1bpot5n/)